# If $\sin(\pi \cos x)=\cos (\pi \sin x)$, then prove that $\cos(x-\pi/4)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Sin and cos are equal at $\pi /4$

Then $\sin x =1/4$ and $\cos x=1/4$

This is where my first problem arises, how can sin and cos have the same value as 1/4? I have tones of problems ahead, but I feel this where I am fundamentally wrong. Please help

Comment: Too many questions https://math.stackexchange.com/users/690228/aditya

Comment: pi cosx need not equal pi sinx.(I'm fact it doesn't here).

Comment: sin(x)=cos(90-x) =cos(90+x) etc for any angle x(in degrees)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I am sorry, but I tend to collect my problems over a few days and ask them all at once. I leave at 30mins of gap between each to make sure the site isn’t a flooded, but if you think I should change my strategy, I will consider. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$\sin(A)=\cos (B) \iff B=\pm\left(\frac \pi 2- A\right)$$

therefore

$$\sin(\pi \cos x)=\cos (\pi \sin x) \iff \pi \sin x=\pm\left(\frac \pi 2 - \pi \cos x\right)$$

$$\iff  \sin x=\pm \frac 1 2\mp  \cos x \iff \sin x \pm \cos x =\pm\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos (\pi \sin x)=\cos(\pi/2-\pi\cos x)$$

$$\sin x=2m\pm(1/2-\cos x)$$

$$\sin x\mp\cos x=2m\pm1/2$$ where $m$ is an integer

But $-\sqrt2\le\sin x+\cos x\le\sqrt2$

But $m=?$